# HTMLUnit and Cloaking

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, gwt, htmlunit, web-crawler

So my question is actually quite simple:

If I put `webclient.setCssEnables(false)`, then It should work faster, right? but will Google consider it as cloaking? (In case you dont know what cloaking is, cloaking is showing different things to users that you would show to the Google bot, or any other bot )

Answer (score 3):

HtmlUnit is a web browser. Why would Google care that you enable or disable CSS in your web browser? Enabling CSS in HtmlUnit doesn't change anything to what a web server serves.

Comment: He's probably using HtmlUnit to create HTML snapshots making AJAX crawlable: http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/html-snapshot.html .